# Checkstyle uses unpredictable config file

Tags: maven, checkstyle

We have a maven project which includes checkstyle as well as pmd as analysers.

The problem is checkstyle sometimes takes my configured and modified google_checks.xml file, sometimes it uses a vanilla goole_checks.xml file and throws checkstyle errors, which are valid for the file it uses but I have no idea where it gets that file from. My pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <!-- checkstyle -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <!-- google checks -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>validate</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
              <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
              <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
              <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>8.20</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>validate</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
              <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
              <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
              <goal>cpd-check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <!-- PMD -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- JXR -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

I removed some parts from the pom that are unrelevant I think.
The full project lies here: https://code.toold.xyz/Hochschule/WebAnServer/src/branch/mavenSetup/CueBox_source

When first executing a mvn clean it works reliably, but when I do a mvn compile and then without changing anything do a mvn compile again. It sometimes throws a lot of errors, about indents... which I removed from the google_checks.xml. It creates a checkstyle-checker.xml in the target folder, and it sometimes contains stuff that isn't in my google_checks.xml file, it looks more like the original google_checks.xml file.

Do you have any idea what causes this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue was with the name google_checks.xml I renamed it and tested it now it works flawless all the time. It seems like maven interpreted the google_checks.xml not as a file name but as a refernce and downloaded it or extracted it from somewhere

If someone is here that knows exactly if this happened... please explain, I'll accept your answer :)